# Is Fock space a symmetric/exterior algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, exterior-algebra, quantum-field-theory, symmetric-algebra

[Wikipedia's Fock Space entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fock_space) says that the Fock space is the direct sum of tensor products of $H$. However, it is not represented as $\bigoplus_{n=0}^{\infty} H^{\otimes n}$, but rather as $\bigoplus_{n=0}^{\infty} S_\nu H^{\otimes n}$, where $S_\nu$ symmetrizes ($\nu=+1$) or anti-symmetrizes ($\nu = -1$) a tensor.

Now my question is, what is the difference between $\bigoplus_{n=0}^{\infty} S_+ H^{\otimes n}$ and $\bigoplus_{n=0}^{\infty} S^n(H)$, where the latter is a symmetric algebra? Similarly, what is the difference between $\bigoplus_{n=0}^{\infty} S_- H^{\otimes n}$ and $\bigoplus_{n=0}^{\infty} \bigwedge^n(H)$, where the latter is an exterior algebra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [two ways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra#Alternating_tensor_algebra) of looking at the symmetrization of $H$:

- as the quotient $S^n(H) = H^{\otimes n}/I$, where $I$ is the ideal generated $I$ by sums of the form $v\otimes w - w\otimes v$;
- as the image of the operator $S_+:H^{\otimes n}\to H^{\otimes n}$ defined by sending generators to their symmetric product
  $$
  S_+(v_1\otimes\cdots\otimes v_n) = \frac{1}{n!}\sum_{} v_{\sigma_1}\otimes\cdots\otimes v_{\sigma_n},
  $$
  where the summation runs over the permutations $(1,\dots,n)$.

The isomorphism $S^n(H) \cong S_+(H)$ follows from the 1st isomorphism theorem by showing that $\ker S_+$ is $I$.

Similarly, the exterior algebra can be defined either as the quotient $\bigwedge^n(H) = H^{\otimes n}/I$ by the ideal generated by sums of the form $v\otimes w+ w\otimes v$, or as the image of the operator $S_-:H^{\otimes n}\to H^{\otimes n}$ defined by sending generators to their antisymmetric product
$$
S_-(v_1\otimes\cdots\otimes v_n) = \frac{1}{n!}\sum_{}\text{sign}(\sigma) v_{\sigma_1}\otimes\cdots\otimes v_{\sigma_n} =: v_1\wedge \cdots\wedge v_n,
$$
and likewise we can obtain the isomorphism $\bigwedge^n(H)\cong S_-(H)$

Comment: Thank you. That was very helpful!